# Unable to get the value of variable outside jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a music player with audio visualization. I want it to function as when I click on the name of track then that track should start playing

```
<script src="main.js"> </script>
<script src="/circular-audio-wave.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var sel2= 'audio/audio3.mp3',
        sel1 = ''; 
    $( "li" ).click(function() {   
        sel1 =  ($(this).data('val'));     
        sel2 = 'audio/' + sel1; 

        console.log(sel2);
    });

    let wave = new CircularAudioWave(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
    wave.loadAudio(sel2);
</script>
```

I want that sel2 value is sent outside the jQuery function so that it can be used by 'wave.loadAudio(sel2);'. As on running this script I am getting only the 'audio/audio3.mp3' playing as I have given this value to variable earlier. 
I want that it sets the new value of sel2 (whichever I click and then pass it to wave.loadAudio(sel2)) so that every time on clicking new track I get that track playing.

Comment: Then put `wave.loadAudio(sel2)` in your function?

Comment: The problem is not that you cannot get the value of `sel2` outside the callback function, the problem is when you're trying to get it. You're accessing it before it is reassigned (before the element is clicked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really understand how callback functions works in javascript, which are asynchronous side of javascript. Your `wave.loadAudio(sel2)` will always get `audio/audio3.mp3` because is loaded before your click function. Look on the simple example:

```
console.log('First');
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Second')
},0);
console.log('Third');
```

If you run this script you will see: 'First', 'Third', 'Second', because callback function is added to the `Callback queue`, and when `call stack` is empty this function is realised, in this way callback function can be using as non-blocking. So in your example you should add `wave.loadAudio(sel2)` to the body click function:

```
var sel2= 'audio/audio3.mp3';
let wave = new CircularAudioWave(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
sel1 = ''; 
   $( "li" ).click(function() {
     sel1 =  ($(this).data('val'));
     sel2 = 'audio/' + sel1; 
     wave.loadAudio(sel2);
});
```

Btw your code has more errors. Try to use default parameters, arrow functions, don't declare global variables (sel1), avoid using `var`, sel1 should be declared inside click function not outside.